# AgentRansack's file list provides right-click file popup menu like Explorer; how can I do this in my own apps?

Tags: contextmenu, windows-shell

if I right-click on a file name in the search results, it gives me the usual Explorer popup menu for a file, with options like Open, Edit, Properties, Share With, Send To. Just like what I get in Explorer itself. How did they do this? Can I do this in my own programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [How to host an IContextMenu](http://www.bing.com/search?q=How+to+host+an+IContextMenu+oldnewthing+site%3Ablogs.msdn.com&go=&qs=n&sk=&form=QBRE) series from oldnewthing. The seris not only deal with displaying the menu, but also shows how to handle different use cases such as property dialog, control or shift key down when menu item is selected, deal with context menu shell extensions, etc.